# mongodb-sink-kafka-connector,BulkWriteError{code=61, message='Failed to target upsert by query :: could not extract exact shard key', details={}}

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, mongodb-kafka-connector

when I try to use a sharding MongoDB cluster to save data from kafka ,it raise an error like

'com.mongodb.MongoBulkWriteException: Bulk write operation error on server 192.168.50.117:20000. Write errors: [BulkWriteError{index=0, code=61, message='Failed to target upsert by query :: could not extract exact shard key', details={}}]'

kafka:v2.7,
mongodb:v 4.2,
connector type: distributed,

I have tried to reset the sharding config and restart kafka server/connector server ,but it does not  work
Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuMs3.png)